# How to implement Plugin concept in magento2

Tags: magento2, plugin

I want to implement plugin after, before and around concept in my Magento 2 website.

**di.xml** :

```
<type name="Magento\Webapi\Model\Soap\Server">
    <plugin name="soap_log" type="training\learning\Model\Webapi\Soap\Server" />
</type>
```

`Magento\Webapi\Model\Soap\Server` has a method `_checkRequest` and it has a `string` type parameter.

Now i want to get that string type parameter in my `_aftercheckrRequest` in `training\learning\Model\Webapi\Soap\Server` class. How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use plugin only for public methods. See [docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html#plugin-limit)

Answer (score 1):

`_aftercheckrRequest` method is `protected` and we cannot use plugin. We can use Plugins only for `public` and `non-static` methods. For example we have one `public function :public function test();`
and plugin:

```
public function afterTest(\Magento\Webapi\Model\Soap\Server $subject, $result)
{
    // your code
    return $result;
}
```

**Note:** `test()` became  `afterTest()` (capital "T")

Comment: That is OK, but if it is public method then how we can get that method parameters in afterTest() ?